# Why is my images not showing up in my Spring Web Flow Project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

Why is my images not showing on in my Spring Web Flow Project.

I have the following code in my jsp page

```
<img src="<c:url value="/images/getacro.gif" />" alt="Get Adobe Reader" align="top" height="31" width="88">
```

but the image is not getting displayed on the web page in my Spring webflow project.  so I checked my tomcat server and I did see the image in:

**apache-tomcat-7.0.29/webapps/Enroll/images**

but I checked the log and I see the 404 error in the log:

[12/Oct/2012:15:04:13 -0400] "GET /Enroll/images/getacro.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 952

but its on the file system.  what could it be.. I think its my spring setup.

here is my mvc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

  <mvc:annotation-driven />



  <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
          p:basenames="messages" />

    <!-- Declare the Interceptor -->
    <mvc:interceptors>    
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
              p:paramName="locale" />
    </mvc:interceptors>

  <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

and here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">


    <display-name>Enroll</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map all /resources requests to the Resource Servlet for handling -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- Spring Security Configuration -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: check the mapping in web.xml file.
or in spring config file .. <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

Comment: no its not that.  I think something in my spring webflow setup is stopping it

Comment: did you tried pasting the complete URL in browser and checked if the image is being displayed properly. ?

Comment: /Enroll is your context root? And the Spring Dispatcher Servlet owns /* (with the exception of /resources/*). So it's not surprising that /images doesn't work. I agree you'd need to reference /resources/images or take a different approach. Have you typed /Enroll/resources/images/getacro.gif to see if at least that is working? In any case, I don't think it's going to be your Webflow configuration.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/Enroll/resources/images/getacro.gif did not work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from you configuration file, since you have a resource servlet, I would say try

`<img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/getacro.gif" />" alt="Get Adobe Reader" align="top" height="31" width="88">`